# javax.crypto.Cipher equivalent code in Nodejs Crypto Javascript

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, encryption-symmetric, javax.crypto

I'm trying to convert below java code into nodejs.

```
public static String encrypt(String accessToken) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        String merchantKey = "11111111111111111111";
        String st = StringUtils.substring(merchantKey, 0, 16);
        System.out.println(st);
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(st.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(accessToken.getBytes());

        // convert the byte to hex format
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedByte.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((encryptedByte[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Here is what I was able to figure out-

```
function freeChargeEncryptAES(token){
    var fcKey = "11111111111111111111".substring(0, 16);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', fcKey, "");
    var encrypted = cipher.update(token,'ascii','hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return encrypted;
}
```

I'm not able to get same output. For example if

> token = "abcdefgh"

Java Code output   - `bc02de7c1270a352a98faa686f155df3`

Nodejs Code output - `eae7ec6943953aca94594641523c3c6d`

I've read from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592607/javascript-nodejs-equivalent-code-for-the-java-code-cipher-dofinalbyte) that by default encryption algorithm is **aes-ecb** which does not need IV. As the key length is 16, I'm assuming `aes-128-ecb` (16*8 = 128) is the algorithm that I should use.

Can someone help me figure out the problem ??

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB. , thanks for the info but my use-case is different. I just want to transform the above java code to nodejs. The java implementation does not specify the algorithm but by default Oracle Java JCE provider uses ECB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to change -

> `crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', fcKey, "");`

to

> `crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', fcKey, "");`

Reason is simple - `createCipher` method treats second parameter as `Encryption Password` while it is an `Encryption Key`.

My bad, even after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592607/javascript-nodejs-equivalent-code-for-the-java-code-cipher-dofinalbyte), I've used wrong method (crypto.createCipher instead of crypto.createCipheriv). Below is proper working code in nodejs. That was all needed.

```
function freeChargeEncryptAES(token){
    var fcKey = "11111111111111111111".substring(0, 16);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', fcKey, "");
    var encrypted = cipher.update(token,'ascii','hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return encrypted;
}
```