# Encrypt string with Blowfish in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, base64, blowfish

I need to encrypt a string but I almost get the output I desire, I read online that it has something to do with padding and iv_vector at the end to complete for the remaining 8 bytes to be same length as txtToEncrypt.

I'm using this library https://github.com/agorlov/javascript-blowfish

```
// function in Java that I need
// javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/NoPadding").doFinal("spamshog")


var iv_vector = "2278dc9wf_178703";
var txtToEncrypt = "spamshog";
var bf = new Blowfish("spamshog", "cbc");

var encrypted = bf.encrypt(txtToEncrypt, iv_vector);

console.log(bf.base64Encode(encrypted));

Actual output: /z9/n0FzBJQ=
 What I need: /z9/n0FzBJRGS6nPXso5TQ==
```

> If anyone has any clue please let me know. I searched all over Google all day.

Comment: What is the strange output you're getting?

Comment: This:   /z9/n0FzBJQ=

Comment: Gotcha.  It's clearly related to the output you're looking for, so that looks like it might be some detail in the module you're using.  If you're still stuck later when I have some time I'll look at the back-end code and see if there are any clues.

Comment: The problem is not in this module itself it's just that I need extra bytes (8) at the end of encrypted string. I just converted this code from a reverse engineering of an android app (basically java) for learning purposes and it uses some functions to complete the remaining bytes.

Comment: I have almost same issue but different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352275/javax-crypto-cipher-equivalent-code-in-nodejs-crypto-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: First of all, the author of that library has no idea what he's doing. There is no reason to use code like that. As for your code: Blowfish has a block size of 8 bytes and your IV is 16 bytes, which probably means that the last 8 bytes are ignored.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that your Java code produces 16 bytes of output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, here is how to encrypt a string in NodeJS with Blowfish

```
// Module crypto already included in NodeJS
var crypto = require('crypto');

var iv = "spamshog";
var key = "spamshog";
var text = "2278dc9wf_178703";
var decipher = crypto.createCipheriv('bf-cbc', key, iv);
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var encrypted = decipher.update(text, 'utf-8', "base64");
encrypted += decipher.final('base64');

console.log(encrypted);  

Returns: /z9/n0FzBJRGS6nPXso5TQ==
```

Comment: Disable `setAutoPadding()` only works is data length is multiple of the block size, in your case 16 / 8 = 2.